# How do I fire the doombringer's Saber Launcher?

Tags: tribes-ascend

The help text states:

> Requires in air locked-on target to fire

I assume this means the target has to be in the air, but ***how do I lock-on the target?***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Sabre launcher will automatically lock-on and acquire targets while equipped. The weapon can be used on opponents while they are either in vehicles or freely traversing the playing field.

Targets can be acquired rapidly, however only one target can be assessed at a time. The following conditions are required to begin locking onto your target.

1. The opponent must be within range of the targeting system. (There is a minimum firing distance)
2. Must be in-air. Or in simpler terms, not touching the ground. (This does not apply to ground vehicles)
3. At or near the area of your crosshairs. (Zooming helps)

Once these conditions have been met a box will appear around your target. This will also be indicated by a distinct beeping sound. Let's call this the "pre-firing" state. During this state the three conditions listed above must be maintained at all times. After a period of ~5 seconds in this state, the targeting box will become red. At this point you have reached the "firing-state". Left-clicking will now fire the sabre rocket.

During the pre-firing state your opponent will be aware that you are targeting him. This is accomplished by both a continuous beeping sound and a HUD message. If your opponent is not in a vehicle this will often prompt the player to land on the ground as soon as possible to disable your ability to track him. As a result, the best strategy is often to click rapidly in anticipation of the firing-state. Once the missile is fired, your opponent will again be notified of this action in their HUD by both a message and a visual indicator showing the missile's trajectory. At this point they can take two actions..

1. Move into a position where there is an obstacle between them and the current path of the missile.
2. Wait until the missile becomes within range and attempt to fire at it in an effort to disable it.

In consideration of the weapon's strengths and weaknesses, the Sabre launcher is best suited to be most effective against enemy vehicles and fast moving (and often high flying) enemy flag cappers.

Comment: The “ground” vehicles are in fact hovering vehicles and also count in the air. Hence, the Saber launcher is *the* anti-vehicle weapon, for all vehicles. Not just for the flying Shrike.

Comment: A quick tip for future Saber users, if you're finally locked onto a target and have fired your missile, *stick around* on the target and often the second lock will be (seem?) quicker and you can pound out another missile or two.  Particularly helpful with shrikes.  Also it's fun thinking that the enemy will be scrambling around under heat for a longer time than they expect.

Answer (score 0):

When the target is in the air an indicator will alert that it is locking on to that target. If I am not wrong, it should target the enemy nearest to the crosshair. After that it will lock and you are allowed to fire only then.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of "how do I lock-on the target?".

Comment: What I meant to say was that it does it automatically as long as you are looking in the general direction with the saber launcher equipped.